# AWS lambda serverless image resizing

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, image-resizing

I was following the below mentioned tutorial for image resizing on the go using Amazon lambda and Amazon API.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway.

After completing all the steps, on testing

http://YOUR_BUCKET_WEBSITE_HOSTNAME_HERE/blue_marble.jpg

displays the required image but

http://YOUR_BUCKET_WEBSITE_HOSTNAME_HERE/300×300/blue_marble.jpg

gives the error {"message": "Internal server error"}

AWS lambda monitor shows the following log.

2017-02-20T12:18:57.979Z c0265015-f766-11e6-932c-ebf25f098e89
{
    "errorMessage": "The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.",
    "errorType": "InvalidRequest",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:538:35)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:668:14)",
        "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:670:12)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
        "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:668:14)",
        "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)"
    ]
}

What am i doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too familiar with node but I have written a post on how to do the same but in python instead. In case you would like to checkout it out:

[Resize image using lambda](http://blog.kaliloudiaby.com/index.php/serverless-image-resizing-aws-lambda-and-aws-s3/)

Comment: Try setting this to your S3 client in the tutorial code.

`AWS.config.update({
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
});`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But now I am getting following error:- Unable to import module 'index': Error
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

Comment: I guessing the issue may be laying on the way the node modules have been built. Check this out [deploy nodejs lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html)

Comment: Few people have the same: [issue](https://github.com/request/request/issues/2364)

Comment: Thanks a  lot. It worked finally. I just had to do **npm install** and upload the lambda function again.